# After upgrade Wheezy to Jessie apache 2 SSL stops working

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, mod-ssl

I upgraded server from Wheezy to Jessie, and Apache 2.4 stops working...

Especially on port 443 there's no ssl ....

```
telnet myhost 443
GET https://myhost
<html><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/><body>Something in /var/www/html/index.html</body></html>>Connection closed by foreign host.
```

It should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.<br />
 Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

SSLEngine is on - yesterday everything works properly, but it was Wheezy, not Jessie...

*** update ***
Fresh mind - I found, that connection to :443 is logged to /var/log/apache2/access.log instead of /var/log/apache2-ssl/access.log But why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution was very hard to find... Only coincidence helps me to find it.

The Apache2.4 requires `.conf` extension....

I had two files: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/http` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/https` and of course the same symlinks in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`.

Trying to find out the solution I took `default-ssl.conf` and made it a symlink, and it works!
So I copied every single line to find where is the difference, and found nothing. I renamed the `https` into `https.conf`, made a symlink and it works too!!!

The biggest mistake is that I create symlinks by myself, not using `a2ensite` - which will yield that `http` site doesn't exist - until renaming it into `http.conf`.

6 hours of searching nothing... Sigh....But maybe this will help someone else..

Comment: solved for me; another sympthom is that, if you try to do a2ensite (or a2dissite) yousite.ext it will tell you your site doesn't exist. After renaming the file adding .conf all worked fine

Comment: You've saved me! I had an opposite problem: Let's Encrypt had generated *.conf files but my normal (non-conf) files with port 80 and SSL rewrite were completely ignored, it was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the release notes on Apache 2.4?

"Notably, the access control directives have changed considerably and will need manual migration to the new directives. "

https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#apache-httpd-incomat

Comment: Yes, few of this changes fits my server, but I _hope_, that changed everything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to use Authorization configuration. It's delay to discover and change.

```
    <Directory /var/www/webalizer>
            Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
    #       AllowOverride all
    #       Order allow,deny
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

The old settings is comment (#). Is it work for you?

Comment: Yes, during debian update almost all settings are corrected